# Save pages of a document as separate documents (explode), but without using PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice-writer

**Context:**

1. I have one .DOC/.DOCX document that is a model for Mail Merge;
2. After using the Mail Merge feature on Word 2019, a new document with hundreds of pages is generated, as expected;
3. I want to save each page as a new document, procedurally/automatically, but the only way I know is "printing" as PDF, then using ILovePDF to "Extract all pages". Then I have hundreds of PDFS;
4. I wanted to do that natively on Word, saving the files as .DOC/.DOCX documents.

**The question:**

1. Is there a way to natively save procedurally/automatically each page of a .DOC/.DOCX as a new document? Which one?
2. If there is no way, which other easiest way there is that doesn't involves printing as PDF?

(The solution can be on LibreOffice Writer or Microsoft Word, it doesn't matter.)

Comment: @KJ I did not understand the question at the end of your comment. Could you please repeat it differently?

Comment: You can try macroses provided by MS support: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-programmatically-save-each-page-or-section-of-a-document-as-a-separate-file-dc3627f7-5805-061f-4c90-039aebeba588